# ngModel not set in Dynamic input in ngFor with add and remove option

Tags: angular, forms, input, angular-ngmodel

Using Angular 4, I have to create a dynamic Input field where users can add and remove input fields.

But I am getting an issue where the same ngModel is getting assigned to all input fields and Set input fields reset on add or remove button.

#### Angular Html Code :

```
<h3> Dynamic Input </h3>

<form (ngSubmit)="SubmitFnc($event)">
  <div *ngFor="let ItmVar of inputAryVar; let IdxVar=index" [attr.Idx]="IdxVar">
  <input type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Name Field"
    [(ngModel)]="ItmVar.nameLbl">&emsp;
    <button type="button" (click)="addDelBtnFnc(ItmVar,IdxVar)">
      {{ IdxVar == inputAryVar.length - 1  ? "[ + ]" : "[ - ]"}}
    </button>
  </div>
  <button > Submit </button>
</form>
```

#### Angular TS Code :

```
export class AppComponent  {
  inputAryVar:any

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(){ 
  this.inputAryVar=[
    {
      "nameLbl":"Field1"
    },
    {
      "nameLbl":"Field2"
    },
    {
      "nameLbl":"Field3"
    }
  ]
  }

  addDelBtnFnc(itmVar, idxVar)
  {
    if(idxVar==this.inputAryVar.length-1)
    {
      this.inputAryVar.push({
      nameLbl:"Field"+(this.inputAryVar.length+1)
    })
    console.log(this.inputAryVar)
    }
    else
      this.inputAryVar.splice(idxVar,1)
  }

  SubmitFnc(event)
  {
    console.log(this.inputAryVar)
  }
}
```

[The Code I tried is on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b73xje)

Not able to figure out why ngModel is not getting set properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because all the input fields are getting the same value for `name` attribute. Assign unique `name` to each input field.

```
<input type="text" name="field_{{IdxVar}}" placeholder="Name Field"
        [(ngModel)]="inputAryVar[IdxVar].nameLbl">
```

Fixed [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wraunk?file=src/app/app.component.html)